# Get and understand database structure respectivelly data model

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What are the best steps how to understand the database one is supposed to work with and for which none of data models exist? Is there any way how to obtain the data model or anything like that which could help?

E.g. someone gets a new job as data miner and it is expected from him to understand the database structure first without knowing a thing, just knows a name of database schema he should work with.

How to get familiar with the data? (using SQL Developer above Oracle DBs)

Comment: I'm afraid you are entering the world of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO a *divide-and-conqure* strategy would be best, since it would be hard to just understand a large system database all-together at once. So, first split your tables into groups: list tables, primary/parent tables, and child tables. You can use an **ER** diagram for this, and maybe naming convention of your tables.

Then you should find the *main or primary* tables that holds things together, usually there would be a few of these, from which one to start is something you should decide or ask your collegues/employer. After you had picked one, understand what the table holds and does for your system, then by checking its constraints find all of its child tables from the group you did in step one. And continue with this cycle until you finish all prime tables.

Usually at this point, you would know which list tables holds what for you (since you examined the data of the prime and child tables)

This is all from my personal experience, and it worked well for me.